# Open museum in NYC for Thanksgiving

Tags: car-rentals, new-york-city, museums, thanksgiving

Are museums going to be open for Thanksgiving? I am also interested about renting a car in NYC, but I cannot find anything open that day. Is the airport the only option?

Comment: there are many museums in NYC, here is a useful site to check their opening times http://www.nycgo.com/schedules-and-admissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what I can see from the websites the only museum that doesn't explicitly state that they are closed on Thanksgiving Day is [NYC Folk Art Museum](http://www.folkartmuseum.org/info) though it is quite likely that they are.

As far as car rental is concerned the major car rental companies like [Avis](http://www.avis.com), [Hertz](http://www.hertz.com), [Budget](http://www.budget.com) have offices open on Thanksgiving in NYC but most of their Manhattan locations (if not all)  report that they don't have any cars for the Thanksgiving day.

You could try [ZipCar](http://www.zipcar.com) but you might have the same luck.